# Apply function to single column of structured numpy array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a structured numpy array with two columns. One column contains a series of date times as strings, and the other contains measured values corresponding to that date.

```
data = array([('date1', 2.3), ('date3', 2.4), ...] 
             dtype=[('date', '<U16'), ('val', '<f8')])
```

I also have a number of functions similar to the following:

```
def example_func(x):
    return 5*x + 1
```

I am trying to apply `example_func` to the second column of my array and generate the result

```
array([('date1', 12.5), ('date3', 11.6), ...] 
      dtype=[('date', '<U16'), ('val', '<f8')])
```

Everything I try, however, either raises a future warning from numpy or requires a for loop. Any ideas on how I can do this efficiently?

Comment: `5*data['val']+1`?

Comment: To clarify, I want to modify the existing array so that I retain knowledge about which date corresponds with which value in `example_func(data['val'])`. I guess I could use your suggestion and then create a new array using `np.array(data['date'], example_func(data['val']))`. However, I was hoping to do this without creating a new array.

Comment: To modify the existing array, simply assign : `data['val'] = ..`?

Comment: This raise a FutureWarning from numpy. To quote the numpy developers "...This code will likely break in a future numpy release..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
In [7]: example_func(data['val'])
Out[7]: array([ 12.5,  13. ])
In [8]: data['val'] = example_func(data['val'])
In [9]: data
Out[9]: 
array([('date1',  12.5), ('date3',  13. )], 
      dtype=[('date', '<U16'), ('val', '<f8')])
In [10]: np.__version__
Out[10]: '1.12.0'
```

I have gotten future warnings when accessing several fields (with a list of names), and then attempting some sort of modification.  It suggests making a copy etc.  But I can't generate such a warning with a single field access like this.

```
In [15]: data[['val', 'date']]
Out[15]: 
array([( 12.5, 'date1'), ( 13. , 'date3')], 
      dtype=[('val', '<f8'), ('date', '<U16')])
In [16]: data[['val', 'date']][0] = (12, 'date2')
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: FutureWarning: Numpy has detected that you (may be) writing to an array returned
by numpy.diagonal or by selecting multiple fields in a structured
array. This code will likely break in a future numpy release --
see numpy.diagonal or arrays.indexing reference docs for details.
The quick fix is to make an explicit copy (e.g., do
arr.diagonal().copy() or arr[['f0','f1']].copy()).
```

Developers aren't happy with how they access several fields at once.  It's ok to read them, but changing is under evaluation.  And in '1.13' there's some change about copying fields by position rather than name.

Comment: This is interesting because for me `data['val'] = example_func(data['val'])` raises a FutureWarning. I wonder if it has to do with the context in which I am using it IRL (my arrays are all in nested dictionaries). Either way, thanks for the insight. I'll most likely continue with this approach.

Comment: I don't see how arrays in dictionaries should make a difference.  If you can construct a minimal example that reproduces the warning, I'll look at it.

Comment: Your right, it doesn't make a difference. I've tried to isolate the behavior and can't create a simplified test case that reproduces the behavior outside the overall code. I'll tinker with it and post an update if / when I figure it out.